# Call angularjs function using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to call angular function using javascript/jQuery, following are the link I found

- [Call Angular Function with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758997/call-angular-function-with-jquery)
- [Call controller function from outside of controller component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709373/angularjs-how-to-call-controller-function-from-outside-of-controller-component)

I have taken the same steps but getting error in browser console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'myfunction' of undefined
```

I have created the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkbharti/8G8xH/3/). How to call myfunction function and alert is displayed? Any Idea?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/VTbNf/

Answer (score 93, accepted):

*Solution provide in the questions which you linked is correct.* Problem with your implementation is that You have not specified the **ID** of element correctly.

Secondly you need to use `load` event to execute your code. Currently DOM is not loaded hence element is not found thus you are getting error.

*HTML*

```
<div id="YourElementId" ng-app='MyModule' ng-controller="MyController">
    Hi
</div>
```

*JS Code*

```
angular.module('MyModule', [])
    .controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myfunction = function (data) {
        alert("---" + data);
    };
});

window.onload = function () {
    angular.element(document.getElementById('YourElementId')).scope().myfunction('test');
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/VTbNf/)

Comment: I forgot to add id in fiddle, sorry for that. And you are absolutely right, problem is with my code run before DOM load. Your code works great. Thanks..,.

Comment: How to do this if controller is the body..! I keep getting the error...! myfunction is not a function

Answer (score 35):

You can use following:

`angular.element(domElement).scope()` to get the current scope for the element

`angular.element(domElement).injector()` to get the current app injector

`angular.element(domElement).controller()` to get a hold of the ng-controller instance.

Hope that might help

Comment: If I could add more than +1 for this, I would.  The third one is the best one here, because I'm not using the $scope which allows me to decouple my code from angular v1.

Comment: Nice.  This led me to be able to call a method from a service/factory with the injector().get('servicename') method.

Comment: `angular.element(document.getElementById('yourControllerElementID')).controller().scope().get();` can we write this code to call angular controller function?

Answer (score 10):

Another way is to create functions in global scope. This was necessary for me since it wasn't possible in Angular 1.5 to reach a component's scope.

Example:

```js
angular.module("app", []).component("component", {
  controller: ["$window", function($window) {
    var self = this;
    
    self.logg = function() {
      console.log("logging!");
    };
    
    $window.angularControllerLogg = self.logg;
  }
});
               
window.angularControllerLogg();
```

Answer (score 7):

Your plunker is firing off

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('MyController')).scope().myfunction('test');
```

Before anything is rendered.

You can verify that by wrapping it in a timeout

```
setTimeout(function() {
   angular.element(document.getElementById('MyController')).scope().myfunction('test');    
}, 1000);
```

You also need to acutally add an ID to your div.

```
<div ng-app='MyModule' ng-controller="MyController" id="MyController">
```

Comment: I forgot to add id in fiddle, sorry for that. And you are absolutely right, problem is with my code run before DOM load. Thanks..,.

Comment: @MdAslam I haven't used angular for anything for 3 years so I'd suggest trying to ask a new question if there's none about doing that already. The only option I can think of is to expose it via the global window object but there might be better ways.

Answer (score 2):

One doesn't need to give id for the controller. 
It can simply called as following

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="HeaderCtrl"]')).scope().myFunc()
```

Here HeaderCtrl is the controller name defined in your JS

Answer (score 1):

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46946700/3852426)

```
// In angularJS script
$scope.foo = function() {
    console.log('test');
};
$window.angFoo = function() {
    $scope.foo();
    $scope.$apply(); 
};
    
// In jQuery
if (window.angFoo) {
    window.angFoo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('YourElementId')).scope();
scope.$apply(function(){
     scope.myfunction('test');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to do that, by creating a hidden element inside your scope (with a ID or css class, up to you), and via javascript you find the element and trigger the click.

**Hidden div example:**

```html
<div class="whatever-class-you-want" id="whatever-unique-id" ng-click="callAngularFunctionThatYouWant()">
</div>
```

**Call you scoped function:**

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('whatever-class-you-want')[0].click();
```

or

```js
document.getElementById('whatever-unique-id').click();
```