# What is the equivalent of ng-blur in ionicframework?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, directive

I have an ionic angular template file like this:

```
<ion-list>
<!-- Search Hotels -->
<div class="list list-inset">
  <label class="item item-input">
    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="hotelSearch" ng-focus="tap.focus()" ng-blur="tap.blur()">
  </label>
</div>

<!-- List of Hotels -->
<ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="hotel in hotels |filter: hotelSearch | orderBy: '-popularity' | limitTo: 10" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/hotels/{{hotel.id}}" ng-show="tap.tapped">
  <img ng-src="">
  <h2>{{hotel.name}}</h2>
</ion-item>
```

It works perfectly when I use it in browser using `ionic serve`. But fails in android simulator. the `ng-focus` can be simulated by using `on-tap`.

What is the equivalent of `ng-blur` in ionicframework?

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
onblur="fnx()"
```

It may work!!

Comment: This will only work if `fnx()`is a global function, not an Angular scoped function.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28317383/719247) pointed me in the right direction: if you defined a similar function in your controller:

```
$scope.blurCallback = function(){
    // do some amazing stuff here ...
}
```

then in your markup you can use:

```
<input ... onblur="angular.element(this).scope().blurCallback()">
```