# ng-if not working with simple javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-if

ng-if is not working when I change the values through simple javascript function.My function is getting called but the changes in values cannot be seen in view. Please refer below code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="span" ng-app='MyModule' ng-cloak ng-controller="MyController">

<div ng-if="!bool">
  This is for true
</div>
<div ng-if="bool">
  This is False
</div>
{{bool}}
<br>
<input type="submit" ng-click = "myfunction('test')" value="ng-if button">
</div>
<input type="submit" onClick = "check1()" value="simple JS button">
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('MyModule', [])
.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
$scope.bool = true;
$scope.myfunction = function (data) {
    $scope.bool = !$scope.bool;
};
});
function check1() {
    angular.element(document.getElementById('span')).scope().myfunction('test');
}
```

When I use `ng-click button` it changes value of `bool` changes, but same doesn't happens with `simple JS button` . Actually I am implementing Angular in a page that already uses jQuery, so I need to use `simple JS button`.

**JS Fiddle** : [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/touchingsky/ufzh7kxp/1/)

Comment: are you using Angular 2?

Comment: @BrunoJoaquim no it's Angular 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call angularjs function using jquery/javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648458/call-angularjs-function-using-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, `ng-click` is able to parse an angular expression.

Second, it handles the reference to the current scope and performs a call to `$scope.$apply` to notify any watchers to update. If you would add a call to `angular.element(document.getElementById('span')).scope().$apply()` in your function, it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use $scope.apply . This is because angulars digest cycle will not know if your value changes outside of its scope like in a simple JS function.

Comment: Hope this helps you.