# Not able to route from the jquery css click in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, single-page-application

I have following click binding with AngularJS which is working fine :
`data-ng-click="vm.newCard()"`

newCard() :

```
  $location.path("xxxx/card/0");
```

which is navigating correctly.

Now, I have following click binding with Jquery

```
 $(".responsiveTableBody").off("click", ".responsiveRow", vm.newCard);
```

click event is executing but it not route to URL

Any ideas on how to route?

Comment: I think function is not executing  put console in it, best build jsfiddle we can understand the problem in a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to call a function that only angularjs know about you would need to get hold of the angularjs scope from jquery and also notify angularjs that this function has been triggered afterwards. Take a look at this similar question [Call Angular Function with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758997/call-angular-function-with-jquery)